# Spamassassin: Where quarantined files goes?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, spamassassin, amavis

I searched a little bit and don't found anything related :(

I need to know where spamassassing send the quarantined files since I need check some data on them.

Any help appreciated.

OS: Ubuntu
Postfix+Amavis+Spamassassin

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I searched using brute force and find out the folder, it is /var/lib/amavis/virusmails/

Comment: /var/amavis/virusmails/ on CentOS